# Is my style of coding - using static object with non-static getter - causing 'memory leaks' or 'performance issues' in my Java app on Heroku

Tags: java, design-patterns, memory-management, static, singleton

I'm running Play Framework 1.2.7 on Heroku, and my app is only functioning because I've rigged it up to restart every ten mins. I would like to get to the bottom of this problem and I suspect the following aspect of my code is the issue.

I hit upon a certain style of coding which involves using a non-static method, with a static instance of an object. I like the way the code reads and can be organised. e.g. If I need a version of the object that has state I instantiate it, if not I just do something like `Obj.instance().theMethod()` however this might be causing problems.

Assuming there is a class called `Shop` I'm doing this:

```
public class Shop{

  // some stuff

  private static final Shop INSTANCE = new Shop();
  public static Shop instance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  // some stuff

  public void doSomething(){
    // do method stuff
  }

}
```

Which I then call in my code like this:

```
Shop.instance().doSomething()
```

Would be much appreciated if you could let me know whether this is a problem.

EDIT: The main issue is, not having studied CS/SE so I just don't have a lot of knowledge to fall back on. If you can point me to some keywords to Google that would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think *this* is causing the memory leak?

Comment: How many objects are we speaking about ? 10 ? 50 ? 10000 ?

Comment: Hmmm now that I think even more, let's just say it's a 'performance issue' ... funny how writing helps you think! Basically there is only one 'copy' of the Shop object available, and everyone is trying to use that. If it's being used by someone else, then it's not available and the app is waiting/pausing ... but I'm not sure

Comment: @Florent Bayle the traffic to this website is not huge - abt 40/hr max, but Google and other search engines are hitting it every second or so in 10 min  that would mean around 60 x 10 = 600 Objects of each Class that gets used

Comment: I don't see any synchronized blocks. Why would anything "wait"?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for that info. Just trying to reason based on what I know. I guess not, which is good.

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms you are experiencing that cause you to restart every 10 minutes?

Comment: your `Shop.INSTANCE` is called a singleton

Comment: As for the question, I don't see how this could cause any memory issues whatsoever. As for your problem, too broad to answer.

Comment: The application becomes very slow to respond to requests. When I restart it becomes fast again. A bit like when you have an old computer and you need to do a restart every now then to keep it running properly.

Comment: @G.Bach thanks - thats still helpful. Knowing it's not a problem is also very helpful.

Comment: As wee don't know what the "doSomething" method does, it's impossible to say if this code will cause any performance issues. If it does simple stuff like print text in console, it's ok, but if it's more complex, like multiple reading/writing in a single file or accessing a database, there could be an issue

Comment: @jhamon doSomething() represents lots of methods, almost all of which do  a database 'select' based on some parameters, so I'm pretty confident that isn't the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'm getting the feeling that 1) this code is fine, 2) the issue has something to do with the Play 1.2.7 on Heroku, I've read some suggestions that all is not 100% with their deployment, but it's hard to pin down, but I'm not qualified to comment on that. I should probably get in touch with Heroku support, thanks again.

Comment: you can use Visual VM to remotely monitor a server to see what it is doing with its memory... I do this frequently. It's a bit of a pain to set up though. I can probably dig out some instructions on how I do it if you get desperate.

Comment: @Neilos that reminds me that it's probably time to get New Relic setup, which has a heroku add on - thanks